# Why won't this Fizzbuzz program in C work?

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

I have litteraly been learning C for a matter of hours and wanted to try a Fizzbizz program to test my knowledge so far.

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i;
for (i = 1; i <21; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            printf("Fizzbuzz\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Fizz\n"); 
        }
    }
    elseif (i % 5 == 0) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            printf("Fizzbuzz\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Buzz\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("%d", i);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

However the compiler returns

> In function 'main':
>   Line 14: error: expected ';' before '{' token

I suspect the error is pretty trivial but can you explain why it doesn't work and if I've at least got the right idea?

Comment: As an aside, you'll never get to the second Fizzbuzz.

Comment: Since `elseif` is not a valid keyword, the compiler is assuming it's a function call, which can't legally be immediately followed by a `{`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elseif` is not a C keyword; you need `else if`.

Also, you probably want a newline in the number case:

```
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need "else if" instead of "elseif", I think.